# insert values into more columns within loop

Tags: sql, loops

I need to insert values into more columns within loop command. 
Table has 3 columns: Id, Name, Surname. I would  like to insert  folowing values  :

- id:      1 2 3
- Name:    John Mike Jane
- Surname:   Lee, Yong, Sommers

```sql
BEGIN 
    FOR v_LoopCounter IN 1..3 LOOP
        INSERT INTO emplo
            VALUES (v_LoopCounter, name ,surname);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Any idea how can I insert it ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that, and you can use the same method you mentioned, assuming your using Oracle.

Comment: yes its on oracle db, but how can I insert all values for all columns in one loop

Comment: I have tried following but without succes :                      `code`                                                             BEGIN 
   FOR v_LoopCounter IN 1..3 LOOP   
    for ver in 1..3 loop          
    for tt in 1..3 loop          
    INSERT INTO emplo      VALUES (v_LoopCounter, name,surname);
  end loop;
 end loop;
    end loop;
END;